# Querying mongoDB via graphene with arguments

Tags: mongodb, graphql, mongoengine, graphene-python

Good morning,

I would like to be able to make a GraphQL request that "ask" MongoDB the following question :

```
query 
{ user(firstname:"Pierre}
    { lastname}
}
```

- To do so I have defined a model.py :

```
from mongoengine import Document
from mongoengine.fields import StringField
class User(Document):
    meta = {'collection': 'user'}
    firstname = StringField(required=True)
    lastname = StringField(required=True)
```

- Then I have defined in Schema.py :

```
from graphene_mongo import MongoengineObjectType
from graphene import connect
from models import User as UserModel

connect(db="graphene-mongo-example",host="127.0.0.1:27017",alias="default")

class User(MongoengineObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):

    users = graphene.List(User)

    def resolve_users(self, info,firstname):
        return list(UserModel.objects.all(firstname))

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

I do not succeed in having only the user with the given firstname..
Could you please help me ?

Many thanks

B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

query 
{ user(firstname:"Pierre} { lastname}}

if above is your graphql query then it should be

query

{ user(firstname:"Pierre"){ lastname} }

Next read this parameter firstname in your code and fetch the document accordingly

Comment: Thanks Ravi for your help. May I ask you if the code I put on my question is correct to handle my request ? At the moment Graphiql is asking me for an id:ID! .... And I am not able to pass a "firstname" as parameter on Graphiql ... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The models.py did not change.
Here is the code I have wrote to answer the problem I had :

```
import graphene
from graphene.relay import Node
from flask import Flask
from flask_graphql import GraphQLView
from graphene_mongo import MongoengineObjectType
from models import User as UserModel
from mongoengine import connect


connect(db="graphene-mongo-example",host="127.0.0.1:27017",alias="default")


class User(MongoengineObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        filter_fields = ['fisrt_name']
        interfaces = (Node,)

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    user_by_name = graphene.Field(User,gName=graphene.String())

    def resolve_user_by_name(parent,info,gName):
       return UserModel.objects.get(first_name=gName)

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)

#==================================================================

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.add_url_rule(
    "/graphql", view_func=GraphQLView.as_view("graphql", schema=schema, graphiql=True)
  )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I am then able to query with GraphQL this kind of request :

```
query { 
userByName(gName:"Pierre")
  {lastName 
   firstName
  }
}
```